# Send rich formatted html email with css using php mailer

Tags: php, css, email, syntax-highlighting

I need to send a rich formated html with lots of css in it.. The problem with mail is that only inline  css works.. and i can use that for some part of the mail. the rest is in need to highlight some codes.. which changes for every email.. what i need is some syntax highlighter that can really glow the different codes like c, c++, java, php etc with syntax colors. And i need to do that in php. What is the best server side syntax highlighter can be used.

Or else is there anyway to email a webpage completely with full css support.

Comment: yes, it's called "inline css". emails are basically a small self-contained world, with very limited possibilities of reaching "outside" to fetch more resources. Consider it a case of "if you don't include it, they won't come"

Comment: @MarcB i know that its the inline css... is there any thing like hyperlight that can only add inline css rather than class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/highlight-source-code-php/

Answer (score 0):

There is [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler), written in Python, which takes an HTML document and converts all the styles to inline CSS. [There is a web page](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/) which shows it working.

If you know Python, or know someone who does, you could probably port it to PHP without much difficulty.

I found it by [Googling "convert css to inline"](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+css+to+inline) - it is the first result, if you look further down the results, you may find a PHP based solution.

PHP source code can be highlighted by using the [`highlight_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) function - I'm sure other languages provide similar functionality, and there are also projects like [this one](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/).

Comment: highlight_string works only for php codes..  and i dont want to run it python dude..

Answer (score -1):

I used something called emogrifier which is written in PHP and it works cool.